# Strip single forward slash from text only in R

Tags: r, string, str-replace, gsub

I am trying to remove only the / from any text using R. I have tried different approaches and I got mixed results.

This is the text I am dealing with `s/p Left IOLI 3/9/04.`

I am trying to produce an output like this `sp Left IOLI 3/9/04.`

Only strip the `/` in text and not numbers.

I have tried these four

```
gsub("\", "", str, fixed=T) 
gsub("/", ".", str, fixed=T)
gsub("[^A-Za-z]", ".", str, perl =T)
str_replace( str, "/", "")
```

So far only `gsub("[^A-Za-z]", ".", str, perl =T)` worked. sucker stripped the `/` off of everything text numbers and everything. I just need the `/` from text be gone. Any help is much appreciated folks.

Comment: Have a doubt.  Suppose you have `s/12 45/p s/p Left` is the string.  What is the exected output?

Comment: @akrun, good question I would expect that show up like this `s12 45p sp Left `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use regex lookarounds to remove the forward slash that are not between numbers.

```
gsub('(?<![0-9])/(?![0-9])', '', str, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "sp Left IOLI 3/9/04."
```

If we also need to remove `/` when either the left or right side contain non-numeric characters,

```
gsub('(?<![0-9])/|/(?![0-9])', '', str1, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "sp Left IOLI 3/9/04." "s12 45p sp Left"
```

#### data

```
str <- 's/p Left IOLI 3/9/04.'
str1 <- c(str, 's/12 45/p s/p Left')
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way is to run multiple regexes. Demonstrated here using str_replace_all of package stringr, but obviously will work using base functions as well.

```
#First correct for / between 2 alphabets like s/p
mystring <- str_replace_all(mystring, "([a-zA-Z])/([a-zA-Z])", "\\1\\2")

#Next, correct for / between 1 alphabet and 1 number like s/12 or 45/p
mystring <- str_replace_all(mystring, "([a-zA-Z])/([\\d])", "\\1\\2")
mystring <- str_replace_all(mystring, "([\\d])/([a-zA-Z])", "\\1\\2")
```